# Incomplete type compilation error with malloc memory allocation

Tags: c, types, malloc

```
static char st[][8192];
void foo ( int tab_size){
    st = (char**) malloc ((tab_size+1)*sizeof(char)*8192);
}
```

I receive the compilation error in "malloc" line that st has incomplete type. What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong is that `st` isn't a `char**`. Also, you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: as a note there is no reason to cast the return value of `malloc` in c, and can actually cause problems, as the `void *` is automatically promoted .

Comment: @twain249 why I don't need here cast from (void*)?

Comment: @TatianaCooper read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @twain249 I get now, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't specify the size of the inner dimension for `st`, the compiler doesn't know how big it needs to be; hence the type is *incomplete*, and you never complete it before the `malloc` call.

Since it looks like your intent is to allocate `st` dynamically, go with Oli's advice and declare it as a *pointer* to an 8192-element array of `char`:

```
static char (*st)[8192];
```

and rewrite your `malloc` statement as

```
st = malloc(sizeof *st * (tab_size+1));
```

`sizeof *st` == `sizeof (char [8192])` == 8192.  This form is a bit cleaner and easier to read.  Note also that in C, you don't have to cast the result of `malloc` (unless you're using a pre-C89 implementation, in which case, I'm sorry), and the practice is discouraged.

This will allocate enough space to hold `tab_size + 1` arrays of 8192 characters each.

It is only within the context of a function parameter declaration that `T a[]` declares `a` as a pointer to `T`.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition for `st` is indeed not a complete type.

Try this instead:

```
static char (*st)[8192];

void foo (int tab_size){
    st = malloc ((tab_size+1)*sizeof(*st));
}
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth it works fine, but I can't get what is now st is. This is kind of array? And what does mean sizeof(*st)?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two completely different types: an array vs pointer to an array.

```
static char st[][8192];
```

declares st to be of type array. It is not a modifiable lvalue and can't be assigned to.

If your intent was to allocate space for an array of integers and assign it to a pointer use the pointer declaration suggested by Oli Charlesworth.

Note that your declaration of st won't allocate space though. if you try something like this, you would get an error..

```
printf("0x%x\n", st);
```

Compiler is treating it like a declaration and expects to see the actual definition elsewhere.
Its not a definition because you haven't given the value for the array's first dimension.